# Conditional recoding of columns in R

Tags: r

I've got a data set which looks in a very rudimentary way like this (it is actually much bigger)

```
frequency      unit
   500          3
   2            1
   400          3
   4            1
   15           2
```

the unit column shows if the frequency is measured in 1=week, 2=month or 3=year.

what I want to do is recode the frequency (to the same or even a new row) so that I do have all the frequencies in the same unit (e.g. divide 15 by 4 and 400 by 52 so that everything is measured in weeks).

I actually tried a lot of stuff like:

```
data$frequency[data$unit == 2] <- data$frequency*0,25
```

but that doesn't work as expected...as it multiplies the first number of the frequency column (500) multiplies  it with 0,25 and displays it...instead of using the number in the same row (15).

```
frequency         unit
       500          3
       2            1
       400          3
       4            1
       125          2
```

instead of...

```
 frequency        unit
       500          3
       2            1
       400          3
       4            1
       3.75         2
```

what I would like to see.

Is there anyone who knows how to handle this problem?...Would be really great :)

Comment: Have you not tried this? `data$frequency[data$unit == 2] <- data$frequency[data$unit == 2]*0.25`

Comment: If I understand your task correctly, you could try sth like `data$frequency / c("1"=NA, "2"=4, "3"=52, "4"=NA)[data$unit]`, where you exchange the `NA` by the denominators.

Comment: To complete @lukeA's answer, it is `data$frequency / c("1"=1, "2"=4, "3"=52)[data$unit]`.

Comment: @lukeA that is very neat, I would consider posting this. Though I don't think you need a named vector, just `df$frequency/c(1, 4, 52)[df$unit]` should be enough.

Comment: Yeah, @lukeA: You should post it. Best answer (which goes a bit beyond this problem) would include an example of using character vectors to index named vectors. For instance discusse the case where the values were "one","two", and "three". For large number of items with the numeric case the `switch` function could also be illustrated.

Comment: @BondedDust Hm I must admit I never found a use case for `switch` in R. How would you do it - like this `f <- function(x, fac) { switch(fac, "1" = x / 1, "2" = x / 4, "3" = x / 52)}; apply(data, 1, function(x) f(as.numeric(x['frequency']), x['unit']))`?

Comment: @lukeA: This worked (because I used your data object which had character rather than factor variables): `f <- function(x, fac) { switch(fac, "one" = x / 1, "two" = x / 4, "three" = x / 52)}; apply(data, 1, function(x) f(as.numeric(x['frequency']), x['unit2']))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With regards to the comments of @DavidArenburg and @BondedDust, here are two ways to do it:

```
data <- read.table(header = TRUE, 
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE, 
                   sep = ";", 
                   text = "
frequency;unit;unit2
500;3;three
2;1;one
400;3;three
4;1;one
15;2;two")

(data$freqNew <- data$frequency / c("one" = 1, "two" = 4, "three" = 52)[data$unit2])
#        3        1        3        1        2 
# 9.615385 2.000000 7.692308 4.000000 3.750000 

data$frequency / c(1, 4, 52)[data$unit]
# [1] 9.615385 2.000000 7.692308 4.000000 3.750000
```